# Typo3 4.5.x highlight search term also in h1 (not just in body)

Tags: typo3, typo3-4.5

Any input how to make that work with `tx_indexed_search`? The searched term is highlighted in the normal bodytext. Also thank to "forwardSearchWordsInResultLink" the word is still marked on the page after the search results.

Currently the searched term is highlighted on the search results and on the following page. But, if the term is on the following page's , then the word has no wrapped . Also if the term is in a link there is no highlighting.

Comment: You should be clearer. What do you want to achieve: highlight the search term on the page users are being redirected to, or in the results list?

Comment: I have just added a few notes on my previous post. We miss, highlighting in links or if the searched term is in <h1> on the second page (the redirected one). The "normal" highlighting in the bodytext works as expected.